# Eigenvalues of Kronecker product of two non-square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, kronecker-product

Let $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ be rectangular matrices. What can we say about the eigenvalues of their Kronecker product $\mathbf{A} \otimes \mathbf{B}$???

One observes that $A$ and $B$ are not square matrices, so we can not talk about their eigenvalues. However, the Kronecker product defines a square matrix and has a set of $nm-$eigenvalues.

I am not asking about the trivial eigenvalues due to the rank deficiency of the matrix $\mathbf{A} \otimes \mathbf{B}$.

Comment: There should exist a connection with **singular values** of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Indeed see theorem 20 in [this document](https://digitalcommons.unf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1025&context=etd). As it is "only" a M.Sc thesis, a little caution...

Comment: Thanks, but its singular values do not say much about the eigenvalues. @JeanMarie